# Running MySQL query for equality between ID, in a table that has multiple IDs

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables

One I need all the columns, let's call it `totalorder`, the other one I just need one column, which is a date, let's call it `orderproduct`. I can match them by a column called `order_id`. The thing is, `table1` has multiple entries for `order_id`, whilst `table2` has just one entry. I need the date from `totalorder` in multiple rows in `orderproduct`.

Here is the MySQL query I've written so far:

```
SELECT
    op.*, op.`date_created`
FROM
    orderproduct op, totalorder to
WHERE
    op.order_id = to.order_id
```

When I ran this query, I get error `#1064`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you add full error text.

Answer (score 2):

`to` is a [keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html) in mysql. so you can not use it as an alias, or you have to escape it using backticks.

```
SELECT
    op.*, op.`date_created`
FROM
    orderproduct op, totalorder tot
WHERE
    op.order_id = tot.order_id
```

or

```
SELECT
    op.*, op.`date_created`
FROM
    orderproduct op, totalorder `to`
WHERE
    op.order_id = `to`.order_id
```